# cant load extension of timescaledb in postgres in selfhost

Tags: timescaledb

data=# CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb;
ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/16/lib/timescaledb-2.14.2.dll": The specified module could not be found.

after creating a normal sql table ..cant able to load timescaledb extension

1. installed as per instruction given in timescaledb
   2.timescaledb-2.14.2.dll it is in the specified path

need to create hypertable ,please nay one solve this

Comment: Hi Jananee, it seems related to this bug: https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/6715#issuecomment-1972843005

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be related to the documentation lacking instructions for installing PostGIS version 3.3.2. Please try installing this version on Windows, as it should resolve your issue.

The solution is mentioned in this public git issue: https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/1613